# nvidia-docker can't talk to: http://localhost:3476/docker/cli/json

Tags: docker, nvidia-docker

nvidia-docker can't talk to http://localhost:3476/docker/cli/json

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/nvidia-docker-compose", line 43, in <module>
    resp = request.urlopen('http://{0}/docker/cli/json'.format(args.nvidia_docker_host)).read().decode()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 154, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 429, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 447, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 407, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1228, in http_open
    return self.do_open(httplib.HTTPConnection, req)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1198, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 111] Connection refused>
```

Answer (score 0):

A fresh install of nvidia-docker-compose fixed this:

```
wget -P /tmp https://github.com/NVIDIA/nvidia-docker/releases/download/v1.0.1/nvidia-docker_1.0.1-1_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i /tmp/nvidia-docker*.deb && rm /tmp/nvidia-docker*.deb
```

Then to test it:

## Test nvidia-smi

```
nvidia-docker run --rm nvidia/cuda nvidia-smi
```

Answer (score 0):

Encountered this also, a customer wasn't managing to run nvidia-docker-compose. Turns out even after reinstallations of docker and nvidia-docker, the query made by nvidia-docker to docker on localhost:3476 was not getting any response (see nvidia-docker-compose code [here](https://github.com/eywalker/nvidia-docker-compose))

I managed to solve this by generating a hand-made docker-compose file as they turn out to be quite simple, follow this example, replace 375.66 with your nvidia driver version and put as many /dev/nvidia[n] lines as you have graphic cards (did not try to put services on separate GPUs but go for it !):

```
services:
  exampleservice0:
    devices:
    - /dev/nvidia0
    - /dev/nvidia1
    - /dev/nvidiactl
    - /dev/nvidia-uvm
    - /dev/nvidia-uvm-tools
    environment:
    - EXAMPLE_ENV_VARIABLE=example
    image: company/image
    volumes:
    - ./disk:/disk
    - nvidia_driver_375.66:/usr/local/nvidia:ro
version: '2'
volumes:
  media: null
  nvidia_driver_375.66:
    external: true
```

Then just run this hand-made docker-compose file with a classic docker-compose command.